# standard deviation !! help!!

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

Here are the table of values:
$$ \begin{array}
1 x_j&n_j\\ 
 450.5&4\\
 510.5&8\\
 570.5&12\\
 630.5&6
    \end{array}$$

$$N=30$$

$$\bar x=550.5$$

$$S_x=\sqrt\frac{\sum_{j=2}^4n_jx_j^2-N\bar x}{N-1}=57.53$$

my explanation $S_X=\sqrt\frac{(4\times450.5^2+8\times510.5^2+6\times630.5^2+12\times570.5^2)-(30\times4\times550.5)}{29}=377.4281389$

solution=$S_x$= 57.53 but my explanation $S_x$=377.428.

where is my mistake??

please teach me

Comment: 30= 4+8+12+6 um...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you simply have the wrong formula: You are missing a square on the $\bar x$ and it should read
$$S_x=\sqrt\frac{\sum_{j=1}^4n_jx_j^2-N\bar x^2}{N-1}.$$
Using this instead of the one you wrote, Wolframalpha [confirms](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7B(4%5Ctimes450.5%5E2%2B8%5Ctimes510.5%5E2%2B6%5Ctimes630.5%5E2%2B12%5Ctimes570.5%5E2)-(30%5Ctimes%20550.5%5E2)%7D%7B29%7D%7D) the result.

Comment: thank you but your formula is 2927.927...  sorry..

Comment: oh!!!! thank you gooooooood!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!